# Reference to an array element in lisp

Tags: arrays, lisp, common-lisp

Is there a way in CommonLisp to store a "reference" or "pointer" to an array element which can be used to update that array element?

In the putmap function below can I call aref just once and store the reference to an array element that I can update later in the function without having to call aref again?

```
(defstruct hashmap data eqt hmf)
(defun createmap  (&key size eqt hmf)
  (make-hashmap :data (make-array size) :eqt eqt :hmf hmf)
  )


(defun putmap (map key value)
  (if
      (null
       (aref
        (hashmap-data map )
    (funcall (hashmap-hmf map) key)
    )
       )
      (setf
       (aref
        (hashmap-data map )
    (funcall (hashmap-hmf map) key)
    )
       (list (list key value))
       )
    (push
     (list key value)
     
      (aref
        (hashmap-data map )
    (funcall (hashmap-hmf map) key)
    )
      
       
       
     )
    )
  )
   




(setf a (createmap :size 10 :hmf (lambda (x) (mod x 10))))



(putmap a 444 2)

(print a)
```

Answer (score 5):

If your intention is just to improve performance and clean up the code, you could use `symbol-macrolet` in this case and save the `(funcall (hashmap-hmf map) key)` to a variable:

```
(defun putmap (map key value)
  (let ((index (funcall (hashmap-hmf map) key)))
    (symbol-macrolet ((place (aref (hashmap-data map) index)))
      (if (null place)
          (setf place
                (list (list key value)))
          (push (list key value)
                place)))))
```

`aref` is still called each time, but the code is more readable and the array index is not recalculated for each call.

Answer (score 2):

Building on RowPJ's answer, here's a macro called `with-array-element` which does not avoid the `aref` calls (but the compiler can probably optimize that as well or better than any human) but does deal with evaluating the indices and the array itself just once.

```
(defmacro with-array-element ((name array &rest indices) &body forms)
  (let ((ix-names (loop for i below (length indices)
                        collect (make-symbol (format nil "IX~D" i))))
        (a-name (make-symbol "ARRAY")))
    `(let ((,a-name ,array)
           ,@(loop for index in indices
                   and ix-name in ix-names
                   collect `(,ix-name ,index)))
       (symbol-macrolet ((,name (aref ,a-name ,@ix-names)))
         ,@forms))))
```

Now, for instance:

```
(with-array-element (x (get-coordinate-array ...) (compute-x-offset ...))
  ... x ... (setf x ...))
```

Will call `get-coordinate-array` and `compute-x-offset` just once.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution to avoiding the re-evaluation of the `aref` expression is to model the update operation as a function, and then define a place updating operator based on that function using `define-modify-macro`.

Suppose we have some array `a` and we wish to do this:

```
;; perform a complex calculation on (aref a i), with extra argument x,
;; and store back into (aref a i).

(setf (aref a i) (complex-operation (aref a i) x))
```

We can define a macro `complex-frob` which does this with the following one-liner:

(define-modify-macro complex-frob (arg) complex-operation)

Test:

```
[1]> (macroexpand '(frob (aref a i) x))
(LET*
 ((#:G3355 A) (#:G3356 I) (#:G3358 X)
  (#:G3357 (COMPLEX-CALCULATION (AREF #:G3355 #:G3356) #:G3358)))
 (SYSTEM::STORE #:G3355 #:G3356 #:G3357))
```

As you can see, this seemingly didn't buy us much, in this particular Lisp implementation. The arguments `a` and `i` of our `aref` are evaluated once into gensyms, and `aref` *per se* is invoked only once. Then an internal function called `system::store` is invoked to store the new value of the element into the array.

I **think** that even though `define-modify-macro` introduces a top-level macro, the function which is targeted, such as `complex-operation` in our example, can be a local one. It's just symbolic substitution.

That allows us to do, e.g.

```
(define-modify-macro complex-frob (arg) complex-operation)


(defun api-function (obj index arg)
  (labels ((complex-operation (old-value arg)
              ...)))
     (complex-frob (aref (get-array obj) index) arg)
     ...))
```

The `complex-frob` updates the array at the specified index, such that the `(get-array obj)` is evaluated only once.

Incidentally, built-in macro `incf` could be defined usng `define-modify-macro`, like this:

```
[1]> (define-modify-macro my-incf (&optional (delta 1)) +)
MY-INCF
[2]> (defvar a 42)
A
[3]> (my-incf a)
43
[4]> a
43
[5]> (my-incf a 10)
53
[6]> a
53
```

The update function here is `+` and the argument `delta` is optional, defaulting to 1.

The point is that `my-incf` is no less efficient than the built-in one.

Here is the built-in `incf`:

```
[31]> (macroexpand '(incf (aref (get-array (car x)))))
(LET* ((#:G3364 (GET-ARRAY (CAR X))) (#:G3365 (+ (AREF #:G3364) 1)))
 (SYSTEM::STORE #:G3364 #:G3365)) ;
```

Here is `my-incf`:

```
[30]> (macroexpand '(my-incf (aref (get-array (car x)))))
(LET* ((#:G3362 (GET-ARRAY (CAR X))) (#:G3363 (+ (AREF #:G3362) 1)))
 (SYSTEM::STORE #:G3362 #:G3363)) ;
```

Exact same expansion.

Let's apply all of the above to `putmap`. Firstly, a properly formatted original, so we can tell at a glance what it's actually doing:

```
(defun putmap (map key value)
  (if (null (aref (hashmap-data map)
                  (funcall (hashmap-hmf map) key)))
    (setf (aref (hashmap-data map )
                (funcall (hashmap-hmf map) key))
          (list (list key value)))
    (push
      (list key value)

      (aref (hashmap-data map)
            (funcall (hashmap-hmf map) key)))))
```

We obviously have a huge common expression here with that `aref`.

But the real issue I'm seeing here is that repetition of `aref` is coming from the `if`, and the `if` itself is completely unnecessary.

The structure is this:

```
(if (null place)
   (set place (list item))
   (push item place))
```

But this is equivalent to just:

```
(push item place)
```

There is no need to handle the `nil` case; if `place` contains `nil` that means it holds the empty list. You can certainly `push` onto an empty list. So as a very first step, I would rewrite the function like this:

```
(defun putmap (map key value)
  (push
    (list key value)
    (aref (hashmap-data map)
          (funcall (hashmap-hmf map) key))))
```

And, we are done.  There is now only one `aref` call. We don't have to use `define-modify-macro`, because Lisp already provides us the modify macro we need: `push`.